# Unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair mingw64_nt-10.0-19044/amd64

Tags: windows, go, dockerfile

I am trying to build Go docker image Windows 10 with build 19044.2130 but giving below error
**cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair mingw64_nt-10.0-19044/amd64**, in current GOOS list mingw64 is not listed as per [list](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/build/syslist.go). Below is the dockerfile

```
ARG OS=linux
FROM golang as build_base
ARG OS
WORKDIR /tmp/auditcompile

COPY go.mod .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN GOOS=$OS go build -o out/audit .
```

Comment: Not all GOOS/GOARCH combinations are supported. `go tool dist list` gives you the list of supported pairs.

Comment: @jub0bs - even that command doesn't list mingw64 OS

Comment: `mingw64 ` and `mingw64_nt-10.0-19044` are not a valid `GOOS` options, and not something the toolchain would set by default. Are you certain you're not overriding `OS` anywhere? (also go1.16 is no longer supported, are you certain you really want that version?)

Comment: @JimB updated the question, now pointing to latest version of goland, but still giving same error.

Comment: Where, how and with which Docker do you run this Docker build?